# I tried to add required attribute but not working

Tags: html, forms

```
<form Action="form.php"   method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <br>Select Program:</br>
  <select name="pro" id="pro" required>
    <option disabled selected>-- Select program--</option>
    <?php

        $records = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT subject From doc");  // Use select query here 

        while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
        {
            echo "<option value='". $data['subject'] ."'>" .$data['subject'] ."</option>";  // 
displaying data in option menu
        }   
    ?>  
  </select>
```

I used the required attribute so that without the selection the form will not be selected. Unfortunately, without the selection the form still posts. What might be wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Use the below code. It will work

`

Select Program:

-- Select program--
<?php

```
        $records = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT subject From doc");  // Use select query here 

        while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
        {
            echo "<option value='". $data['subject'] ."'>" .$data['subject'] ."</option>";  // 
displaying data in option menu
        }   
    ?>  
          </select>`
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
<form Action="form.php"   method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <br>Select Program:</br>
      <select name="pro" id="pro" required>
        <option disabled selected></option>
        <?php

            $records = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT subject From doc");  // Use select query here 

            while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
            {
                echo "<option value='". $data['subject'] ."'>" .$data['subject'] ."
```

";  // 
        displaying data in option menu
                }   
            ?>  
                  
----
the problem was -- Select program--, i've solved it. Thank you